# Is there any XML Parser that comes by default with g++

Tags: xml, parsing, g++

PHP, C# is bundled with such parsers and are available with the default libraries. 
Does g++ have any such libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G++ is a compiler, not a development framework.

If you want a C++ XML library, try [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/).